# Webpack: Copy JSON-files via file-loader

Tags: javascript, json, webpack

I am using Webpack's `module.loaders` and `file-loader` to copy several js-files when compiling:

```
module.loaders = [
    { test: /app\/locale\/moment\/.*\.js$/, loader: "file-loader?name=locale/moment/[name].[ext]" }
];
```

This works fine for me.
I want to do the same thing with JSON-files:

```
module.loaders = [
    { test: /app\/locale\/.*\.json$/, loader: "file-loader?name=locale/[name].[ext]" }
];
```

But this time it doesn't do anything.
Why does Webpack make a difference between js- and json-files when using the file-loader?

Comment: Are the `*.json` files `require`d anywhere? If not, it won't work.

Comment: Ah! I used to require them but now I just load them via ajax!

Comment: You can tell webpack to load certain modules / data dynamically, if you don't want to include this data in the main bundle: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html.

Comment: Yes, the same for me. I want to load json content and copy it to my public dir. How to be?

Answer (score 4):

This is an adaptation of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47762160/1510445) to my own similar question.

You can copy JSON files via file-loader by adding the following code to you Webpack config:

```js
module: {                                                                    
    rules: [  
    // ...  
    {                                                                        
       test: /\.json$/,                                                       
       loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].json'                                 
    }
    // ...
    ]
}
```

There are two nuances here: 1) file-loader will only copy files that are imported/required somewhere in your code and 2) file-loader emits a path to where the file was loaded, rather than the contents of the file itself.

So, to copy a JSON file you'll first need to import it, for example:

```js
const configFile = require('../config.json');
```

Since file-loader emits a path to the where the file was loader, `configFile` has the value `"/config.json"`.

Now the contents of the JSON file can be loaded however you like, such as with [jsonfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile)

```js
jsonfile.readFile(configFile, function(err, obj) {
    console.log(obj);
});
```

or with Angular's [HTTP](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) package

```js
http.get(configFile).map(res => res.json()).catch((error: any): any => {
    // ...
}).subscribe(obj => {
    console.log(obj);
});
```