# Bundle JSON as a plain JSON file with Webpack

Tags: javascript, json, webpack

I have a web-app that requires a configuration JSON file which contains end-points and other required start-up parameters.

If I use the json-loader, the file is not "real json", it'll look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    "name": "foo",
    "key": true,
};
```

What I would like is plain old JSON which means it can be parsed and changed as part of a deployment process before being sent to the web server where it will be served from.

An alternative is to use the file-loader.  However, that means that (even though it's a trivial task) I have to write the code to download the file myself.  I would like to have webpack handle this and be available.

Is there a way that I can `require` a JSON file, which is written as a plain-old JSON file and imported at run time?

Comment: Very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180983/webpack-copy-json-files-via-file-loader?rq=1

Comment: Why not just use `fs` and read the file?

Comment: Unsure what you mean. If it's in the browser, this can't work. If you mean as part of Webpack's build, how would this help?

Comment: @RayBooysen Are you using Webpack2? You can import JSON files with Webpack2. Note that webpack understands only JavaScript.

Comment: Hi @zero.  I am using webpack 2.  As discussed, importing JSON files uses the JSON-loader and means your json looks like the example above.  I.e. it looks like module.exports = {}.

Webpack understands any type of input as long as there is a loader that supports it. CSS-Loader, Typescript loaders etc.

Comment: Hello @Ray Booysen! Yes, and you want “real” JSON to be bundled with webpack? I think your only (non-hack) option is to use file-loader, as you mentioned yourself. json-loader will be used otherwise and it will produce `module.exports = {}`, https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can `require` a JSON file, which is written as a
>   plain-old JSON file and imported at run time?

Webpack acts on compile-time. That means when you require a file, it loads that file, performs modifications as specified by the loader-chain and exports you the final result from that chain. So what you're asking for sounds like a loader, that acts like a file-loader, but exports an IIFE that returns a promise for the required file.

In theory it's possible to have a webpack loader, lets say an *async-file-loader* that gets the input from the file-loader will handle the async requst for you. Let's assume something like:

```
const promisedFile = require('async-file-loader!file-loader!./myJson.json');
promisedFile.then(file => { console.log(JSON.parse(file)); });
```

But then the whole logic for handling the request would be boundled within that call. The async-file-loader would look something like this:

```
module.exports = function(source) {
    return `module.exports = eval("(function(url){
      /* define async request func, preform request and return promise in here */
   })(${url})")`;
}
```

Pretty nasty...

When you want to load your json-file in runtime, I'll see 2 options:

1. use the file-loader and request the json file asyncronously on your own.
2. use a server-sided scripting language and inject the config into the .html file. If your're using nodejs and express for example on your backend side, you could easily inject the config using [Cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) before serving the request.

Comment: Thanks @ShabbY.  Option 1 is exactly what we're doing now, but was hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

As ShabbY said above, Webpack is a module bundler and compiles your files ahead of time.

It sounds like you need to add a configuration file (json) after build time to be accessed at runtime. For this, a solution would be to load the file using a normal ajax call rather than attempting to bundle it with Webpack.

Comment: Understood.  However, I guess what I want is a loader, that given a file just pulls the file from the web. Similar to the file-loader.