# Webpack 2 and react production

Tags: reactjs, variables, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

Is it possible when I build my project `npm run build` to generate config files where we can change a few variable value on the fly without rebuilding the whole project every time I change a value?

The config file need to be in `.json` or in `.js` and will contain variables like : updateDelay, pageNumber, path, graphQlUri... Variables that are used in the projects and can be changed by the user.

If it's possible how I'm doing it?

Thanks

Comment: Config files for what? In what format? Depending on what? You do realize that `npm run build` can run anything, right? You need to be a lot more specific in your question.

Comment: a config file in .json or in .js who contain variable like : updateDelay, pageNumber, path, graphQlUri... Variables that are used in the projects.

Comment: Follow up this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054416/bundle-json-as-a-plain-json-file-with-webpack

Comment: thanks i'll take a look