# Importing JSON in TypeScript does not import the contents but a URL

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am trying to import the contents of a JSON file in TypeScript but instead of the contents of the JSON, I get its URL.

`App.tsx`

```js
import * as videosInfo from './videos-info.json'

console.log("Print");
console.log(videosInfo);
```

console output:

```
Print
http://localhost:3000/src/videos-info.json
```

In `tsconfig.json` I use `"resolveJsonModule": true`.
How can I consume the *contents* of the JSON and not its path?

EDIT: Here is my `webpack.config.js` for reference:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: '[name][ext][query]'
        }
      },
      { 
        test: /\.css$/, 
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'client.bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 3000
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of bundler or something that could be interfering? That seems like it should work otherwise...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added my `webpack.config.js` for reference. I don't know what could be interfering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@T.J. Crowder` rightfully suggested the problem comes from my misunderstanding of the `asset/resource` loader in `Webpack 5`. According to the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/):

> asset/resource emits a separate file and exports the URL. Previously achievable by using file-loader.

My goal here is to copy `videos-info.json` from `/src/` into the `/dist` folder when I do `npm run build`, so that I can host it statically somewhere and set up an AWS Lambda to overwrite it on regular intervals. Therefore, I **cannot** load the JSON inside the `client.bundle.js` through Webpack because the data will be hardcoded in the bundle. This note about how Webpack builds resources statically helped me understand it better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44424933/9698467

Therefore I **must** use `asset/resource` loader in Webpack 5 to produce a URL, which I can later load into the webpage via a `React hook` for example:

```js
const videosFile = require('./videos-info.json');
// videosFile is a URL

React.useEffect(() => {
  const resp = await fetch(videosFile);
  const data = await resp.json() as VideoResult;
  const videos: VideoResultItem[] = data.items;
}, []);
```

Comment: Don't forget to check `resp.ok`, more on [my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).