# Configuring Angular via a JSON file with Webpack

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, webpack

My Angular app is configured with a JSON file. I was loading it via an HTTP GET, but recently decided to include it directly by adding JSON support to TypeScript with a Definition file:

```js
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

And then importing it where needed:

```js
import * as config from '../config.json';
```

This works great; `config` is the JSON object itself.

The problem is that I'm bundling with Webpack and I want the JSON file to be in the package, but not bundled with anything else, that is, `config.json` should be its own file in the package, rather than being bundled with other files.

I tried doing this with [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) and [move-file-loader](https://github.com/assertible/move-file-loader):

```js
module: {                                                                    
    rules: [  
    // ...  
    {                                                                        
       test: /\.json$/,                                                       
       loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].json'                                 
    }                                                      
    // OR                                                                    
    {                                                                
        test: /\.json$/,                                                     
        loader: "move-file-loader?name=[name].json!json-loader"              
    }
    // ...
    ]
}
```

This prevents the JSON file from being bundled and places it where I want it in the package, but it also makes `config` become the relative path to the JSON file, i.e., `"./config.json"`, rather than the JSON object itself.

Any thoughts on why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently file-loader emits a path to where the file was loaded, rather than the file contents itself. So

```js
import * as config from '../config.json';
```

making `config` into a string containing a path to the file is the correct behavior.

As far as move-file-loader is concerned, since I'm using it with json-loader, the contents of the "moved" file is actually a TypeScript module definition, and it seems to still be loading a bundled version of the file rather than the "copied" version.

These insights lead me to the following solution: First of all, we'll copy JSON files using file-loader in the Webpack config:

```js
module: {                                                                    
    rules: [  
    // ...  
    {                                                                        
       test: /\.json$/,                                                       
       loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].json'                                 
    }
    // ...
    ]
}
```

Then we'll import the file path emitted by file-loader using TypeScript's require syntax

```js
const configFile = require('../config.json');
```

This import method doesn't require the JSON definition file I mention in my question.

Lastly, we can load the file from its file-loader path via an HTTP GET:

```js
http.get(configFile).map(res => res.json()).catch((error: any): any => {
    // ...
}).subscribe(config => {
    // ...
});
```

where `config` is the parsed contents of the JSON file.

I won't mark this as the answer right away in case someone knows how to get this working without HTTP.

Comment: I try to follow your answer but webpack build fails with `Module parse failed: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'export default __web...'` DO you have any ideas to what it could be related?

Comment: @DicBrus I can't be sure without seeing your code but it looks like there's a syntax error in your JSON file. Honestly, I ended up switching back to loading my JSON via HTTP GET because the code was cleaner and easier to maintain.