# How to copy a json file with the webpack copy plugin and include the version from package.json file?

Tags: json, webpack, firefox-addon-webextensions

I would like to copy my manifest.json file (for web extensions) into the build/ folder and use the webpack.DefinePlugin to replace the version in the manifest.json file with the version of the package.json file.

How can I do this? (sorry for my bad english!)

I have already tried it with the file loader (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180983/webpack-copy-json-files-via-file-loader) question) but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I do not have enough reputation yet to add a comment, but there is another way to do this – by using the CopyWebpackPlugin instead of the DefinePlugin. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54700817/7770056) on a related question for an example setup.